# Kivy + Revmob on Android

Tags: android, python, xml, kivy, revmob

I'm trying to implement revmob in a kivy game I'm making for Android and iOS.  Currently, I can't get the ad to show.  The rest of the application works perfectly.  I've only tested it one a Galaxy Note 3 running Android 4.3.  I've followed all of the instructions in the revmob SDK documentation, but it never actually shows the ad.  I believe the problem is that my AndroidManifest.xml is not formatted properly with permissions and activities etc.  Here is my buildozer.spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Runner

# (str) Package name
package.name = runner

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = com.remolten.runner

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ogg,txt

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_dirs = bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version.regex = __version__ = '(.*)'
version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version = 1.2.0

# (list) Application requirements
requirements = kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1


#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions Remolten added some for revmob and uncommented
android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,READ_PHONE_STATE,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 14

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#android.minapi = 8

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path = 

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
android.add_jars = %(source.dir)s/libs/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
android.manifest.intent_filters = revmob.xml

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# List as sections
# 
# You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
# Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
# Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
# Instead of doing:
#
#     [app]
#     source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
# This can be translated into:
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns]
#     license
#     data/audio/*.wav
#     data/images/original/*
#


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Profiles
#
# You can extend section / key with a profile
# For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
# HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
# and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#     [app@demo]
#     title = My Application (demo)
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#     images/hd/*
#
# Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#     buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

And my revmob.xml that I try to add the activity with:

```
<activity android:name="com.revmob.ads.fullscreen.FullscreenActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
</activity>
```

And lastly the look of the AndroidManifest.xml the application gets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.remolten.runner.runner"
          android:versionCode="20004"
          android:versionName="2.0.4"
          android:installLocation="auto"
          >

  <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"

        android:xlargeScreens="true"

        />

  <application android:label="@string/appName"
               android:icon="@drawable/icon"
               android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
               >


    <meta-data android:name="fullscreen" android:value="1"/>
    <meta-data android:name="wakelock" android:value="0"/>


    <activity android:name="org.renpy.android.PythonActivity"
              android:label="@string/iconName"
              android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|screenSize"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:process=":python"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            >


      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>





        <activity android:name="com.revmob.ads.fullscreen.FullscreenActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
</activity>


    </activity>







  </application>

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />



  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />



  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />






<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
</manifest>
```

Could someone post a working version of their buildozer.spec + AndroidManifest.xml with revmob working or help me here?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In your buildozer.spec you use the `android.manifest.intent_filters` but it is not intended to add an activity.

To add a revmob activity to AndroidManifest.xml you need to edit a template file:

```
/path/to/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/default/templates/AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml
```

Like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="{{args.package}}"
          android:versionCode="{{args.numeric_version}}"
          android:versionName="{{args.version}}"
          android:installLocation="{{ args.install_location }}"
          >

  <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        {% if android_api >= 9 %}
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        {% endif %}
        />

  <application android:label="@string/appName"
               android:icon="@drawable/icon"
               android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
               >

    {% for m in args.meta_data %}
    <meta-data android:name="{{ m.split('=', 1)[0] }}" android:value="{{ m.split('=', 1)[-1] }}"/>{% endfor %}
    <meta-data android:name="fullscreen" android:value="{% if args.window %}0{% else %}1{% endif %}"/>
    <meta-data android:name="wakelock" android:value="{% if args.wakelock %}1{% else %}0{% endif %}"/>


    <activity android:name="org.renpy.android.PythonActivity"
              android:label="@string/iconName"
              android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode{% if android_api >= 13 %}|screenSize{% endif %}"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:process=":python"
              android:screenOrientation="{{ args.orientation }}"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            >

      {% if args.launcher %}
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.renpy.LAUNCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="{{ url_scheme }}" />
      </intent-filter>
      {% else  %}
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      {% endif %}

      {%if args.ouya_category %}
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <category android:name="tv.ouya.intent.category.{{ args.ouya_category }}"/>
      </intent-filter>

      {% endif %}

      {%if args.intent_filters %}
        {{ intent_filters }}
      {% endif %}
    </activity>

    {% if args.launcher %}
    <activity android:name="org.renpy.android.ProjectChooser"
              android:label="@string/iconName">

      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    {% endif %}

    {% if service or args.launcher %}
    <service android:name="org.renpy.android.PythonService"
             android:process=":PythonService"/>
    {% endif %}

    {% if args.billing_pubkey %}
    <service android:name="org.renpy.android.billing.BillingService"
        android:process=":python" />
    <receiver
        android:name="org.renpy.android.billing.BillingReceiver"
        android:process=":python">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    {% endif %}


    <activity android:name="com.revmob.ads.fullscreen.FullscreenActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    </activity>


  </application>

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="{{ args.min_sdk_version }}" android:targetSdkVersion="{{ args.sdk_version }}"/>
  {% if args.wakelock %}
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  {% endif %}
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  {% for perm in args.permissions %}
  {% if '.' in perm %}
  <uses-permission android:name="{{ perm }}" />
  {% else %}
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.{{ perm }}" />
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% if args.billing_pubkey %}
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  {% endif %}


{{ manifest_extra }}
</manifest>
```

**NOTE:** Looks like there is some bug in revmob-android-sdk with the fullscreen ad:
[Revmob `Unexpected error on create Fullscreen Ad`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204225). But popup and link work fine.